# Numerous XML documents: how can I capture occurrence and max length of text

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

I have a large number of XML documents I need to loop over and capture how many times the a child node occurs and the max length of the field.  I am able to properly parse the XML, and can capture the count and the length of the field.  What I am unsure of is what datatype and method would be most effective to capture the analysis of the XML documents.

The output I would like to produce is (not in this format - just the data):

```
field1: count = 2, maxlength = 4
field2: count = 2, maxlength = 1
```

Here is an example:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

#sample data:
xml = ['<data><field1>100</field1><field2>1</field2></data>', '<data><field1>1000</field1><field2>2</field2></data>']

#loop to capture fields and length
for item in xml:
    x = ET.fromstring(item)
    for child in x:
        fieldname = child.tag
        fieldlength = len(child.text)
        print(fieldname, fieldlength)
```

I can count the occurrence using this:

```
fields = {}

for item in xml:
    x = ET.fromstring(item)
    for child in x:
      if child.tag in fields:
        fields[child.tag] += 1
      else:
        fields[child.tag] = 1
```

How would I go about capturing the total number off occurrences of a field and the max length `(if fieldlength > maxlength then fieldlength else maxlength)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a defaultdict that if the element does not exist resolves to the default value you specify (see the example below). On each iteration then all you'll have to do is:

```
max_length[child.tag] = max(max_length[child.tag], len(child.text))
```

Full example:

```
#  Necessary import
from collections import defaultdict

#  Create the default dictionary. The argument is a function that generates
#  the default value (that is returned if element is not set). int() returns    
#  zero, thus we will use that, but you could as well have said          
#  defaultdict(lambda : 0)

max_length = defaultdict(int)

for item in xml:
    x = ET.fromstring(item)
    for child in x:
      #  Assign max. You are fine if max_length[child.tag] do not exist yet
      #  because defaultdict will resolve it to 0.
      max_length[child.tag] = max(max_length[child.tag], len(child.text))
```